# SDL image does not display

Tags: c++, sdl

I am currently trying to create a button class that looks as follows.

```
void Button::apply_image(std::string path) {

    SDL_Surface* loaded_image = NULL;
    loaded_image = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    m_button_image = SDL_DisplayFormat(loaded_image);
    SDL_FreeSurface(loaded_image);

}

void Button::show(SDL_Surface* screen) {
    SDL_BlitSurface(m_button_image, NULL, screen, &m_box);
}
```

When using the class, I do the following:

```
Button button1(0,0,50,50);
button1.apply_image("images/cards/1.png");

SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;

screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
SDL_WM_SetCaption("House Of Cards", NULL);

button1.show(screen);
SDL_Flip(screen);
```

My problem is, the image is not displayed when I use `SDL_DisplayFormat(loaded_image);`  But when I get rid of that line and the `SDL_FreeSurface(loaded_image);`.  I then change `loaded_image = IMG_load(path.c_str());` to `m_button_image = IMG_Load(path.c_str());` the image will show up.  Am I doing something wrong, because the path is obviously correct, because the image will show when I don't call DisplayFormat().  Through the use of gdb, m_button_image is NULL and I don't understand why it is, because gdb also shows that loaded_image points to an SDL_Surface*.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what the problem was.  I was calling SDL_DisplayFormat before I had initialized a screen.  Because I had the functions in the wrong order, SDL_DisplayFormat did not have a surface to convert the image to.

Answer (score 0):

from http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormat :
'If the conversion fails or runs out of memory, it returns NULL'

So it looks like the call to SDL_DisplayFormat is failing for some reason, it would probably be useful to do a check for m_button_image==NULL after the call to SDL_DisplayFormat, and if it is NULL to use SDL_GetError() to see what the error was

If that doesn't help then i'm not sure what would, though you could do a slower conversion by blitting the un-converted image to a display formatted surface, and using that as the image (pretty much the same but a bit more convoluted, would really just avoid the call to SDL_DisplayFormat)